# Can I add sounds to Xcode's Storyboard mode?

Tags: xcode, audio, storyboard

I'm new to creating apps for iOS and I'm using storyboard mode. I wanted to know how can I add sounds. Also, does it require coding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this for playback of simple sounds. It uses the `AVFoundation` framework, which will require you to add AVFoundation to your project, and use `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

```
- (IBAction) myPlayAction {
    AVAudioPlayer *data;
    NSString *name = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SoundName"];
    NSString *source = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:name ofType:@"mp3"];
    if (data) {
        [data stop];
        data = nil;
    }
    data=[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath: source] error:NULL];
    data.delegate = self;
    [data prepareToPlay];
    [data play];
}
```